# ConcurrentLinkedQueue does'n work as expected

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an Andoid App that is made of a Service running in Background and some Activities connected to that Service. The Service runs on it's own Process.

My Service mainly has 3 classes: ServiceMain, ServiceWorker,Message.

ServiceMain has all the functions that are used by the Activities like logIn,logOut,send ... and so on.

Message represents a message that is sent to our server or recieved. Simply a String and a bool where the String is the message and the bool is a flag saying if a response from server is needed.

ServiceWorker is a subclass of Thread and does all the sending an recieving of messages using Sockets.

ServiceMain contains 2 Queues:

```
Queue<Message> Sendingqueue= new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Message>(); 
Queue<Message> Recievequeue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Message>();
```

If the logIn method is called a ServiceWorker is created and started. In it's constructor it gets references to both queues and holds them.

```
private final Queue<Message> Sendingqueue;
private final Queue<Message> Recievequeue;
```

ServiceMain then creates some messages (M1,M2 for example) and adds them to the Sendingqueue.

The ServiceWorker builds the connection to our server and then runs into a loop where it looks for messages in Sendingqueue, sends them and doing some othe stuff like recieving ....

Hope the scenario is clear now.

Within ServiceWorker something strange happens on Sendingqueue:

Let's say ServiceMain added two messages, M1 and M2 to Sendingqueue while ServiceWorker is doing something time consuming or is not connected to our server. 
Sendingqueue now contains two messages.

If the ServiceWorker next time gets the length of the Queue it sees 2 items. Ok so far.
Then it calls peek() (the message is removed only if it was successfull sent) on the Sendingqueue and **should** get M1 because it was added first.
But it gets M2. 
The Sendingqueue seems to be reverted.

What's going wrong here ? What can I do to avoid this?

Thanks for any constructive reply.

Detlef

Comment: Try to provide a [sscce](http://sscce.org/) because it's hard to see what you are doing wrong from prose only. Are you sure you are adding to the tail and peeking from the head or vice versa?

Comment: I will try to make an example to reproduce this.

Answer (score 0):

ConcurrentLinkedQueue doesn't make any guarantees about order, but the order of elements shouldn't change if you are adding to the end and taking from the start (or visa versa) thsi should work.  You could run into a problem if you add and remove from the start or end as this will mean you are processing the newest rather than the oldest each time.

If you had a large powerful server, I would still suggest this approach is overkill.  Instead of having a background thread to perform the processing, I would use the main thread.

Note: The socket is already an input and output queue on the client and on the server, so adding a third layer of queuing may be redundant in a large system and inefficient in a smaller device.

Comment: I just read the [api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) and it seems to guarantee that: The head of the queue is that element that has been on the queue the longest time. The tail of the queue is that element that has been on the queue the shortest time.

Comment: A "queue" would be pretty darn useless if it didn't guarantee order. It wouldn't even live up to its name!

Comment: Two threads running concurrently add to the queue at almost the same time, there is no guarantee which will add first.  Once added the order should be guaranteed.

Comment: You are right ,oers and BeeOneRope, a queue should garantee order. FIFO. But in my case it does not, or does but it reverts the order. The reason why I put the sending and recieving in a own thread is that the service should not block if no network is availible.

Comment: Peter Lawrey: There are two queues. Every thread writes only to one of them. ServiceMain writes to Sendingqueue and reads from Recievequeue, ServiceWorker reads from Sendingqueue and writes to Recievequeue.

Comment: What useful thing is it going to do if there is no network? There is already two "queues" in the socket itself.

Comment: If the socket itself was disconnected or had broken pipes my service would have to run in a lopp tryring to reconnect. This would block the service and with that the UI. Using the queues my service can create a message, put it to the queue and return. Fire and forget. The service takes care aubout the message being transmitted successfully within a certain amount of time and will inform the user if not.

Comment: I would do the (re) connection, reading, processing and writing in one background thread. i.e. everything the connection does is in a background thread.  Only when there is something interesting for the UI would I pass a task to it to perform.  I would have notify the user when there is a delay in connection and when there is a delay in getting the expected response.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - of course there is no "guarantees" if two threads are concurrently writing to a queue with no coordination between them, but nor would you expect any (it's not clear how you would even state such a guarantee - given special relativity).

The guarantee you *can* make is that if an item is added *before* another one, where before has a specific meaning the Java memory model, it will appear before that other element in the queue.

So the guarantee is simply that - it's a FIFO, and if you can show that one element went in before, it will be first.